# Sqlmap waf bypass

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, asp.net, sqlmap

This is my first post here, sorry for my english.

Im making some test around, because i want to learn more about sql injection. Im not really good as manual sql injection, so im using sqlmap.

what im know from my target is:
Asp.net application
Mysql database
Powered by plesk and probably ModSecurity Waf. There is a Waf, not sure is modsecurity but Plesk use it.

Im sure some url are vulnerable. But you can reach vulnerable url only as logged user. And when i try to use sqlmap, my asp. session get istantly killed.

What i have tested and work better:

--skip-waf, because the sqlmap waf test, trigger the waf and my session was killed.

--delay 7/8 second

--tamper="modsecurityversioned,randomcomments,between" make the test during more, but on last test crash on paylod with = character.

Can i have some suggestion? What is the most undetected method ? BLind, time, error?
Tamper suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed the default user agent ?

Comment: Yeah of corse, with --random-agend and with some selected user agent. This is not the problem